# Is it right, if first pass of Bubble Sort put smallest bubble in 0th position?

Tags: java, sorting, bubble-sort

From GeeksforGeeks I found this defination :

> Bubble Sort is the simplest sorting algorithm that works by repeatedly swapping the adjacent elements if they are in wrong order.
>
> Example:
>
> ```
> First Pass:
> ( 5 1 4 2 8 ) –> ( 1 5 4 2 8 ), Here, algorithm compares the first two elements, and swaps since 5 > 1.
> ( 1 5 4 2 8 ) –>  ( 1 4 5 2 8 ), Swap since 5 > 4
> ( 1 4 5 2 8 ) –>  ( 1 4 2 5 8 ), Swap since 5 > 2
> ( 1 4 2 5 8 ) –> ( 1 4 2 5 8 ), Now, since these elements are already in order (8 > 5), algorithm does not swap them.
>
> Second Pass:
> ( 1 4 2 5 8 ) –> ( 1 4 2 5 8 )
> ( 1 4 2 5 8 ) –> ( 1 2 4 5 8 ), Swap since 4 > 2
> ( 1 2 4 5 8 ) –> ( 1 2 4 5 8 )
> ( 1 2 4 5 8 ) –>  ( 1 2 4 5 8 )
> ```
>
> Now, the array is already sorted, but our algorithm does not know if it is completed. The algorithm needs one whole pass without any swap to know it is sorted.

What if I do this in reverse order like from n-1 to 0? Is it right because I am putting my array's smallest bubble into the first position on the first pass.

I have written my code like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    for (int j = array.length - 1; j > 0; j--) {
        if (array[j - 1] > array[j]) {
            int temp = array[j - 1];
            array[j - 1] = array[j];
            array[j] = temp;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: if u do this in reverse, after the first iteration the smallest value should be at [0].

Answer (score 2):

Yes, your code will work.

But in order to increase the efficiency of your program in terms of speed, you should change the condition in the second `for` loop. As you have written

```
for (int j = array.length - 1; j > 0; j--) {
    ...
}
```

Here, in the Second Pass, when the value of `j` is 1 then, it will unnecessarily check this condition

```
array[j - 1] > array[j]
```

Because, After the first pass, `array[0]` is already the smallest. So, you don't need to check that again.

And in the third pass, there will be two unnecessary conditions and so on and so on.

Therefore, I recommend you to use `j > i` as the condition of second `for` Loop. Then your whole line will be

```
for (int j = array.length - 1; j > i; j--) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The idea is finally to sort the list.

Below is the Python code for filling the lowest number first and then going to the highest number

```
def selection_sort(input_list):
    for init in range(0,len(input_list)):
        pos_of_min=init        
        for nxt in range(pos_of_min+1,len(input_list)):
            if input_list[pos_of_min]>input_list[nxt]:
                pos_of_min=nxt
        input_list[init]=input_list[pos_of_min]
        input_list[pos_of_min]=input_list[init]
    return input_list


arr_unsorted=[25,67,23,21,90,89,45,63]
sorted_result=selection_sort(arr_unsorted)
print(sorted_result)
```

Comment: The question was asked in Java, not in Python.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32197860)

Comment: Sure, @Japhei. Thanks for your input, I'll work towards it.